# NSTableView with Dropdown Menu and having Image inside Menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nspopupbuttoncell

Yes, is it possible to have:

1. A table having two column ( Should be easy)
2. One of Cell should have image and that should be selectable from Drop - down menu
   By googling what i came to know it has to be of type NSPopupButtonCell type, but i want only image inside it, no text,
   How can i do that ?
3. The another column would be editable, user should be able to type in that.

it would be great if i can get any reference code to implement the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did it with following way,

In Coloumn 1 select the DataCell and assign it of type NSPopupButtonCell, by default it wouldn't come, you need to select it explicitly.

In the Code add following lines of Code...

```
NSTableColumn *option = [pTableColumns objectAtIndex:[pTableView columnWithIdentifier:OPTION_COLUMN_NAME]];
NSTableColumn *shortCutItem = [pTableColumns objectAtIndex:[pTableView columnWithIdentifier:SHORTCUT_COLUMN_NAME]];

// we want first cell to have the Image & Menu 
//Data type column drop down
NSPopUpButtonCell *dataTypeDropDownCell = [option dataCell];//[[NSPopUpButtonCell alloc] initTextCell:@"" pullsDown:YES];
[dataTypeDropDownCell setBordered:NO];
[dataTypeDropDownCell setEditable:YES];

NSArray *dataTypeNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"NULLOrignal", @"String", @"Money", @"Date", @"Int", nil];
[dataTypeDropDownCell addItemsWithTitles:dataTypeNames];
```

Add following code to set the correct MenuItem

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex{

    if([[aTableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:OPTION_COLUMN_NAME]){
        NSPopUpButtonCell *dataTypeDropDownCell = [aTableColumn dataCell];


        [dataTypeDropDownCell selectItem:[ dataTypeDropDownCell itemAtIndex:3]];
    }

}
```

Now only pending this is to append Image inside MenuItem which is not a big deal at all,

Again thanks for Looking at this, let me know if any other approach is there to do so....